# Динамическое создание кнопки в адаптере

Tags: android, java

Кто нибудь может подсказать как это можно реализовать? Хотя бы примерно. Пользователь кликает на чекбокс и динамически создается кнопка над этим листвью. Если нажал на следующий чекбокс создается еще одна кнопка и т.д.

```
  cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

          getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).selected = isChecked;
          if (isChecked)
          {
                      //где-то тут надо что-то делать
              tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006600"));
          } else
          {
              tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("002200"));
          }

     }
});
```

Вот так происходит создание кнопок:

```
LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Privet);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
               Button button = new Button(this);
               button.setText("privet");
               button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
               lin.addView(button);
    }
```

В том классе, где я создаю листвью и связываю его с моим адаптером. Но мне нужно этот код как-нибудь вынести в адаптер.

Comment: разобрался.

Comment: в конструкторе адаптера передаю ему LinearLayout. и в адаптере в событии change для чекбокса динамически создаю кнопки и добавляю их так: lin.addView(button); но почему-то код выполняется дважды. почему?

Comment: Можешь поподробнее описать что ты хочешь?

Comment: Можно не создавать кнопки, а сразу занести их в item_view и при нажатии на чекбокс изменять видимость